# Преобразование List<String> в Map<Character, List<String>>

Tags: java, java-stream

Нужно преобразовать **список** из слов в **мэп**, где ключем является первая буква слова, значением - список слов, начинающихся на указанную букву, с использованием потоков Stream API.

Пока удалось собрать только мэп, где в значениях лежит только список из одного слова, как собрать список из нескольких слов не могу понять.

```java
List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(words);

Map<Character, List<String>> initialMap = wordsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.charAt(0)
        ,t -> Collections.singletonList(t)
        ,(e1, e2) -> e1
    ));
```

Прошу помочь, хотя бы в какую сторону думать.

Comment: Я не эксперт в Java streams, но разве `groupingBy` не делает именно то что вам надо?

Comment: Да, спасибо, это оно

Answer (score 2):

Как было отмечено в комментарии, в простейшем случае достаточно использовать [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

Также нет необходимости строить список `wordList` из массива слов `words`, чтобы получить стрим строк, достаточно использовать [`Stream.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) или [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-):

```java
Map<Character, List<String>> initialMap = Arrays.stream(words)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.charAt(0)));
```

Для получения мапы, отсортированной по ключам, можно использовать [такую разновидность коллектора `groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```java
SortedMap<Character, List<String>> sortedMap = Stream.of(words)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> Character.toLowerCase(e.charAt(0)),
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.toList()
    ));
```

---

Ещё один вариант может использовать метод `forEach`, который унаследован в списке из интерфейса `Iterable` [`Iterable::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), и в стриме [`Stream::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

При этом результирующая мапа будет создаваться заранее и заполняться при помощи метода [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), чтобы создавать значения в мапе (пустые списки):

```java
Map<Character, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>(); // или любой нужный тип

Arrays.stream(words)
// Arrays.asList(words) // допустимый вариант
      .forEach(s -> map.computeIfAbsent(s.charAt(0), k -> new ArrayList<>())
          .add(s)  // List::add - добавили элемент
      );
```

Comment: Как еще вариант, можно сделать и без использования groupingBy: `wordsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.charAt(0),  s -> new ArrayList<>Collections.singletonList(s)),  (list1, list2) -> { list1.addAll(list2); return list1; }));`

Comment: Да, как вариант первоначального ответа такой способ возможен, но при этом будут создаваться лишние объекты-списки.